# Java constructor having broader access level than its class

Tags: java, constructor, access-modifiers

Java specification allows a class with default access to have its constructor public access, what is the purpose of it, since it cannot be referenced outside its package?

Comment: I see this question more like why a constructor can have a wider access than the class. I don't see how any of the answers explains this.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to make this a comment, but since no code tags are allowed in comments....

In regards to your comment on CristopheDs answer:

```
package bob;

class MySuperHiddenClass {

  public MySuperHiddenClass() {
        System.out.println("bob");
  }
}
```

And

```
package bob;
public class MyPublicClass extends MySuperHiddenClass {

}
```

No constructor was declared in MyPublicClass, but you can still call new MyPublicClass from any package.

Comment: You could call new MyPublicClass from any package even if the constructor of MySuperHiddenClass were not public. I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking for why you can have `public` constructors: it's because you can for example call them explicitely (or implicitely) when you *extend* a base class.

Comment: Yes, but there is no purpose of having a public constructor if the class connot be extended from a different package.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I could not understand it until @user439407 illustrated the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Class visibility determines how the outside world create instances of the class. hence package private classes can only be instantiated within the package they are declared. method visibility (including constructors) determines how the instance, already instantiated can be used outside its class definition.

If you declare a package private class, with a private/protected construtor, how will you instantiate it from another class in the same package?

Two things:
class visibility - determines how instances are created outside their defining packages.
method visibility (including constructors) - determine how the access to the members are controlled, regardless of package visibility.